# Google App Engine - ImportError: No module named edf

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have several .py files in my Google App Engine project and I decided to group them together in a directory. However when I tried to access one I get an error:

ImportError: No module named edf

Previously my directory structure was:

```
app_name
-edf.py
-jkl.py
```

Now it is

```
app_name
-folder_name
--edf.py
--jkl.py
```

I tried to change the app.yaml line

```
- url: /edf
  script: folder_name/edf
```

Comment: try with a dot instead of :

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: missing __ init __.py?

Comment: I just added an empty init file but I still get the same error.

Comment: script: folder_name.edf

Comment: on some operating systems \ is used to separate paths, and in some / is used. so python uses . instead

Comment: The . trick worked. You should add it as an answer so that I can accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the dot character '.' to separate the paths rather than the colon in your original example.

On some operating systems \ is used to separate paths, and in some / is used. So python uses . instead to be os-independent at that level.

You can read some discussion on this here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/